# How to make adhitz ads responsive for mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, ads

I have placed Adhitz ads code on my blog but they don't reduce their width according to screen size. How can I make them responsive so they acquire screen width. If it isn't possible then there should be a way so that banners are displayed of reduced size on mobile devices and the same banner of full size on desktop devices.
Thanks